# Mssql-2012 with Rails-2.3.18 what version of SQL adapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am migrating my Ruby (1.8.7) Rails (2.3.18) application database  into MSSQL-2012 Database.

I have followed all the configuration information and made.  The Sql adapter I am using is activerecord-sqlserver-adapter  (2.3.24).

When I load the application I got a error. The error says  **" The current version support only Mssql 2005,2008** " error.

How can I proceed, As of now **I can't upgrade or downgrade  my Ruby on Rails versions and MSSQL versions.**

Is this any way is there to proceed with current set up and versions . Plz help me

Comment: Maybe you can use a ODBC driver instead of the more specific MSSQL Driver.

Comment: @palani. how did you end up solving this issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to update your adapter.  Looking at the Github page, it should support 2012

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Answer (score 0):

So, if you haven't figured out a way to fix this yet, you can create a new initializer file and drop the following code in it.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SQLServerAdapter
      alias :old_initialize :initialize

      def initialize(logger, config)
        begin
          old_initialize(logger, config)
        rescue NotImplementedError => e
          unless e.message =~ /Currently, only #{SUPPORTED_VERSIONS.to_sentence} are supported./
            raise e
          end
        end
      end

      def sqlserver_2012?
        @database_year == 2012
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no driver for SQL Server 2012 and rails 2.x

You need to upgrade to Rails 3.2, as this is the first version of the SQL Server gem that supports 2012.

You can take a look at [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/3.2.13/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SQLServerAdapter) to check the different versions.